# (node:1572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: profile validation failed: education.0.fieldsofstudy: Path `fieldsofstudy` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find the root cause of this validation error:`(node:1572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: profile validation failed: education.0.fieldsofstudy: Path fieldsofstudy is required.`
This is happening even I changed the "fieldsofstudy" to some other names, such as "majors". The same error message will still return.

Here is my profile code for education

```
// @route   POST api/profile/education
// @desc    Add education to profile
// @access  Private
router.post(
"/education",
passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
(req, res) => {
const { errors, isValid } = validateEducationInput(req.body);

// Check Validation
if (!isValid) {
  // Return any errors with 400 status
  return res.status(400).json(errors);
}

Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
  const newEdu = {
    school: req.body.school,
    degree: req.body.degree,
    fieldofstudy: req.body.fieldofstudy,
    from: req.body.from,
    to: req.body.to,
    current: req.body.current,
    description: req.body.description
  };

  // Add to exp array
  profile.education.unshift(newEdu);

  profile.save().then(profile => res.json(profile));
  });
 }
);
```

Here is my code for the education tab

```
data.school = !isEmpty(data.school) ? data.school : "";
data.degree = !isEmpty(data.degree) ? data.degree : "";
data.fieldofstudy = !isEmpty(data.fieldofstudy) ? data.fieldofstudy:"";
data.from = !isEmpty(data.from) ? data.from : "";

if (Validator.isEmpty(data.school)) {
  errors.school = "School field is required";
 }

if (Validator.isEmpty(data.degree)) {
    errors.degree = "Degree field is required";
 }

if (Validator.isEmpty(data.fieldofstudy)) {
   errors.fieldofstudy = "Field of study field is required";
 }

 if (Validator.isEmpty(data.from)) {
   errors.from = "From date field is required";
 }

 return {
   errors,
  isValid: isEmpty(errors)
 };
};
```

Comment: The data. fieldofstudy is part of my const newEdu, also even I switch the variable to data.majors, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: This issue is resolved after I restarted my machine and re-configurate the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your model. When you are creating your profile schema in your models folder, you have accidentally named it `fieldsofstudy` instead of `fieldofstudy` (singular). The fields in the validation has to match the fields in the model.